# Alternative intuition behind series simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series, education, algebra-precalculus

Given functions
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j
$$
the following simplification
$$
f(x)g(x)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j \right)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ib_jx^{i+j}
$$
is relatively intuitive. I guess a rather simple and informal proof would consist in expanding a few terms and recognize the emerging pattern. For example,
$$
(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots)\\
=a_0b_0+a_0b_1x+a_0b_2x^2+\cdots+a_1b_0+a_1b_1x+a_1b_2x^2+\cdots
$$
and recognize this as a double summation. However, I fear some of my students might be confused by it. Is there a more straighforward way to argue in order to justify the intuition behind such simplification?

Comment: I can't see correctly the first formula: the upper and lower parts of it are hidden or cut off. I have checked your coding, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: That is weird. After "Given the functions"? I can see them fully.

Comment: Yes, the first formula.

Comment: That is odd. Happened the same to me yesterday, on a different question, but I can see it clearly.

Comment: I have tested it in Edge and it renders properly. But in Chrome it does not. I don't have Firefox at hand now.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it works. Curious. I wonder how rendering is affected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100430/discussion-between-ajotatxe-and-sam-wolfe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intuition, it's just
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\right)\cdot c=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^ic $$
with $c:=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j$, i.e., 
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j\right)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(a_ix^i\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j\right) $$
followed by 
$$c\cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j\right) c=\sum_{j=0}^\infty cb_jx^j $$
with $c=a_ix^i$, i.e., 
$$a_ix^i\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ib_jx^{i+j} $$
end therefore after summation 
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j\right)=
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ib_jx^{i+j}$$

Comment: This plus the fact that products of analytic functions are analytic and power series are unique, if they want further justification.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, then $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ and the same thing applies to $g$. But then, if $f(x)g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$:

\begin{align}c_0&=(f\times g)(0)=a_0b_0;\\c_1&=(f\times g)'(0)=f(0)g'(0)+f'(0)g(0)\\&=a_0b_1+a_1b_0;\\c_2&=\frac{(f\times g)''(0)}2\\&=\frac{f(0)g''(0)}2+f'(0)g'(0)+\frac{f''(0)g(0)}2\\&=f(0)\frac{g''(0)}2+f'(0)g'(0)+\frac{f''(0)}2g(0)\\&=a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0\end{align}

and so on…